# High power screen mode in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I write a game in Lua with Corona SDK. After some minutes of game playing, the screen goes to low power mode (it is less lighted). How can I cause to the screen to remain in High power mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

```
system.setIdleTimer( false )
```

See here for more info.
http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/systemsetidletimer